# RPM Spec file %setup macro when you don't know the root name?

Tags: rpm, macro, rpm-spec

How do I use the %setup macro if I don't know the root name of the archive. For example, in my case I have `archive.tar.gz` that extracts to

```
myproject-<githsha>/
```

Each time I run that I may get a different `gitsha`. How can I configure that to work with a `.spec` file using `%setup`?

Version looks like this,

```
Version:        1.11
```

What I want is something like `--strip 1` from tar.

Answer (score 2):

you can just use:

```
%prep
%setup -q -c

%install
cd myproject-*
# continue installation here
```

the `-c` option:

> %setup expects the archive to create its own top-level directory. If this isn't the case, you'll need to use the -c option.

from http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-inside-macros.html